# передача строковой константы в качестве аргумента

Tags: c++

Изучал C++ по видео на YouTube, потом захотел изучить его по подробнее и выбрал книгу Роберта Лафоре "ООП на C++", в главе "Массивы и строки"(293 страница) есть код, в котором строковую константу передают в метод класса в качестве аргумента:

```
void part::setpart(char pname[], int pn, double c) 
 { 
 strcpy(partname, pname); 
 partnumber = pn;
 cost = c;
 }
```

```
int main(){
    part part1;
    part1.setpart("Строка", 42, 200.00);
}
```

Я уменьшил код и показал проблемный участок кода. В книге у автора код успешно выполняется, а у меня выскакивает такая ошибка:
**warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*'**

Comment: Это предупреждение - вы приводите константный указатель к неконстантному при вызове функции. Измените сигнатуру так `void part::setpart(const char pname[],`.

Comment: В книге(2004 год) написано без оператора const, это связано с появлением других стандартов C++?

Comment: Попытка преобразовать указатель на неизменяемый объект (массив char из литерала) в указатель на изменяемый. `setpart(char const * const pname, int const pn, double const c)` Книга - говно мамонта. Это все было безобразно и недопустимо уже на момент ее выхода в 2004 году. Ну а в актуальном С++ вместо сырого указателя стоит использовать string_view

Comment: До C++11 обычный строковый литерал мог быть неявно преобразован в тип `char*`. Начиная с C++11 такое неявное преобразование запрещено.

Comment: Спасибо, что посоветуете, бросить книгу или дочитать её?

Comment: Возьмите книгу посвежее. Или например есть разные курсы в интернете в записи. В любом случае не стоит рассматривать стандарте ранее С++11.